# What does mean by glows warmly and transfixes in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110912/synopsis)

> They take back the valuable item -- kept in a briefcase, it glows
>   warmly and transfixes whoever looks at it.

What does mean by glows warmly and transfixes in this sentence?

Comment: it describes sth attractive. see glow and transfix in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temperature words are sometimes used to describe colors.  Reddish colors are warm and bluish colors are cold.  Since light can give color to things, temperature words also can be used to describe lights.  So *glows warmly* describes something that gives off a glow somewhere around red in the color spectrum.

---

*Transfix* comes from a Latin word meaning "pierced through," and *transfix* can still mean this - e.g. *The zombies had corpses transfixed upon fence posts."

Things that visually stand out from the the surroundings can be said to logically "pierce through" your vision, in a sense, if for some reason their appearance would capture anyone's attention.

So if something has a quality where anyone who would look at it would be compelled to stop what they are doing and go "whoa!", *transfix* is a word to describe that.  The idea is that something is so compelling to look at that it stops you from moving.

Something that glows in a briefcase is certainly a candidate for transfixing those who look at it.